# How to add an existing user into the Administrators group through WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I wanted to add an existing user to the Administrators group but unable to do so. Using custom table I can add the user to the group I have created through script but not in the groups already created. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: You can always try a custom action. It's supported by the Windows API, so you shouldn't need a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

As insta said you can use the Group, User, and GroupRef elements from http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_group.htm like so:

```
<util:Group Id="AdminGroup" Name="Administrators"/>
...
<Component Feature="ProductFeature" Id="LocalSQLAdminGroupComponent" Guid="SOMEGUID" KeyPath="yes">
   <util:User Id="AdminUser" Domain="[%USERDOMAIN]" Name="[%USERNAME]" >
      <util:GroupRef Id="AdminGroup"/>
   </util:User>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what the Group element is for?  You can use it to search for the Administrators group, follow that up with the User you create, then inside the User tag, GroupRef the Administrators group.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_group.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time google-fu-ing anything for you. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132958) is a KB article on programatically managing user privileges. It might be what you're looking for.

Basically, you'll be writing a VBScript (or C++ or C#) custom action to access the Windows API and add the user to the group.